# Probability of N-dim Gaussian marginalized over a plane, and a likelihood of a point on a plane

Tags: regression, multivariate-normal-distribution

Context: I'd like to fit a series of coordinates, each with their uncertainties, to a (hyper)plane. I am trying to derive the likelihood for a point on a plane observed at a point. I need a verification of what I did and, **if possible, a source that I can cite**.

Suppose a point $\vec{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^N$ follows a Gaussian distribution,
$$
\vec{x}\sim\mathcal{N}(\vec{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma})
$$
and a plane in the space given as
$$\hat{n}\cdot\vec{x}=k$$

Q1. If I integrate the probability distribution over all points on the plane, I derive the (signed) distance between the point and plane, $h$, to follow
$$
h\equiv\hat{n}\cdot\vec{x}-k\sim \mathcal{N}(-k+\hat{n}\cdot\vec{\mu},\hat{n}\cdot\mathbf{\Sigma}\cdot\hat{n})
$$
**Is this correct one?** I derived it using the properties of multivariate Gaussians [on the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions); affine transformation the coordinates so that the coordinate along the first axis becomes $r$, then finding the marginal distribution by taking inner product with $\vec{e}_1$.

Q2. Assume that the probability, $P(h(\vec{x})|\hat{n},k,\vec{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma})$ in Q1 is correct. On the context of regression, suppose we observed a point on $\vec{\mu}$ with a covariance $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. Is
$$
P(h(\vec{x})=0|\hat{n},k,\vec{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma})
$$
the correct expression for a likelihood of parameters determining the plane, $\hat{n}, k$?

Comment: its a little overkill, but I think the matrix cookbook contains the facts you need, to get you started with a source. https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf